# What is wrong in my code regarding Divisors and prime factors?

Tags: primes, factors

We have to check if there exists an integer A such that it has exactly X positive integer divisors and exactly K of them are prime numbers
[This is my code but it is showing wrong answer after submitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaJJW.png)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to ask a good question.
Specifically, include a description of the problem you are trying to solve and steps you have taken so far.
Please include your code in the question itself instead of linking to a picture of the code.

That said, I would like to point out  to anyone answering that this is a question from an [ongoing codechef contest](https://www.codechef.com/APRIL20B/problems/STRNO). You may want to wait till the contest ends before answering, though it's not required.

Answer (score 0):

In *codeChef* you need to take input in stdin format. Try replacing `map(int, input.split())` by

```
import sys 
map(int, sys.stdin.split())
```

Answer (score -1):

because your code is wrong in case of 5 2
r = 4
then x>4
your code shows ans 1
but real ans is 0